# iOS PullToRefreshView, add didFinishRefreshing method

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I am utilizing PullToRefreshView by Grant Paul and was wondering if it is possible to add a didFinishRefreshing method to the code so that I can call a couple events when its done doing its thing. How would I go about doing this?

Here is the code that you call to stop the refreshing process:

```
- (void)finishedLoading {
    if (state == PullToRefreshViewStateLoading) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
            [self setState:PullToRefreshViewStateNormal];
        }];
    }
}
```

But I do not where to go from here.

Comment: Can you please detail what exactly are you trying to achieve? Why is that you cant add that in above method? And is it possible to use [UIRefreshControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html. This supports from iOS 6 onwards.

Comment: I just wanted to have a method that is called when the PullToRefreshView is done refreshing. Like mapViewDidLoad or webViewDidFinishLoading etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing the `pullToRefreshViewShouldRefresh` method like so:

```
- (void)pullToRefreshViewShouldRefresh:(PullToRefreshView *)view
{
    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //refresh data source here

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            //Code here is run when the above is complete
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [self.pullView finishedLoading];
            //Perform any additional tasks here
        });
    });
}
```

where `pullView` is your `PullToRefreshView` instance.

Answer (score 0):

The pull to refresh is just a visual thing. Surely you have a method that's 'refreshing' things then you call 'finishedLoading' when it's done?
Can you not use the completion of your refresh method to do what you need?

Comment: That's the thing. The refresh method I have written can be called 2 ways, 1: by the PullToRefreshView and 2: by a UISwitch on another view. The event I described in my question is a UIAlertView being shown. I only want the UIAlertView to show at the end of my refresh method when it is called by the PullToRefreshView, not the switch. That's why I though having a method called when the pull to refresh view is done would have been a nice thing, that way the UIAlertView is only shown when the PullToRefreshView is used. If that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

While I like sooper's answer, in more complicated scenarios (e.g. you have different view controllers want to be informed of a background update that may already be in progress), you can use [notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i). Thus,

- any view controller (or any object) that needs to know about the completion can register for the notification via [`addObserver`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-CHDCIGGB) or via [`addObserverForName`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-SW1);
- the selector/block for that notification can do whatever ending of the refresh indicator you need;
- if and when the view no longer needs to receive the notifications (e.g., you're dismissing it, or whatever), you can perform [`removeObserver`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-CHDBABDE); and
- the update process can then perform the [`postNotificationName`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-CHDBAFID) when the update is done, allowing the observers to do whatever UI updates are appropriate.

This is overkill for simple situations, but it is a useful pattern for more sophisticated scenarios.